# Change how account information looks on another website

Tags: html, css

I currently use bill.com to have customers pay but here is my issue..

When you go to https://app.bill.com/p/trinhsdemoaccount it does not render very nicely for mobile...but I was able to strip that down and make it look better with some new css that I made it load under another html page/link.

My main concern is that after I login...all the information it displays in there and how it shows it..i want to make it more mobile friendly...so is it possible to optimize the css/design on that end? I know its not mine, but I was able to strip the login page can I do the same here? Just seems a bit more tough.

http://pastebin.com/QU5NMdMm   <--- Link to inside the account panel...it is very basic in there.

Any suggestions please I am open to. Thank you dearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){}
```

And everything inside of those brackets will only be rendered when the screen width is less than 800px (ie, on a mobile device).

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: So when I get into the account login side of it and im actually into the account details.....should I save that whole page and then add what you said and then just re upload under my own link?